# How to load external content to a div using jquery (think embedded lightbox)

Tags: jquery, thickbox

Using Thickbox is great it allows me to load external sites into the thickbox and they retain their functionality, appearance, etc.  I know how to load simple content into a div with jquery but I am stuck on how to load external content to a div in a page (preferably via onload event) and have that div act like Thickbox and retain the functionality and appearance without the popup thickbox window.

All of the sites are in different child directories but have the same parent.

I hope I explained it well enough.

I am using jquery 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd just go for an iFrame, which from your description I think would provide the same functionality.

Comment: I am not sure if this would be a new question or not, but is there a simple way to embed an iframe in a div?  I was tinkering with jframe.js last night with no success.

Comment: <div ...><iframe ...>Content to show if the frame is disabled</iframe></div>

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery load function is great.

A simple example of code is `$('#result').load('simple/test.html');` where `#result` is the div where you will load external file and simple/test.html is the html page path to load.

For more info just go to http://api.jquery.com/load/ and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Thickbox *is* (usually) an iframe .. iframe is pretty much your only solution for this if the content is from foreign websites (sites you dont control) ..

Comment: I control all of the sites and can take care of the css pretty easily, but I am trying to avoid tinkering with all of the internal pathing of those sites (they are php, perl, and ruby) and I was hoping to be able to pass their directory into a div.  I suspect iframe will be best.  Thank you.